# Utilising Savitzky-Golay Filter in R vs Python

Tags: python, r, scipy, differentiation

I'm currently trying to render the same results in `R` as in `Python` but think I must be misunderstanding the Savitzky-Golay filter. I have the below `Python` code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
t = np.linspace(0,1,10)
X = np.vstack((np.sin(t),np.cos(t))).T
sfd = savgol_filter(X, window_length=5, polyorder=3, axis=0)
sfd
array([[-4.78900581e-07,  9.99997881e-01],
       [ 1.10884544e-01,  9.93841986e-01],
       [ 2.20394870e-01,  9.75397369e-01],
       [ 3.27190431e-01,  9.44944627e-01],
       [ 4.29950758e-01,  9.02837899e-01],
       [ 5.27408510e-01,  8.49596486e-01],
       [ 6.18361741e-01,  7.85877015e-01],
       [ 7.01688728e-01,  7.12465336e-01],
       [ 7.76378020e-01,  6.30281243e-01],
       [ 8.41469460e-01,  5.40300758e-01]])
```

From my understanding, this smooths the matrix and prepares it to develop the derivative term. However, when using `pracma` in `R` (the most recently updated version of a Savitzky-Golay function), I get:

```
library(pracma)
t = seq(0, 1,length = 10)
X = t(rbind(sin(t), cos(t)))
savgol(X[, 1], fl = 5)
[1] 1.229175e-16 1.108826e-01 2.203977e-01 3.271947e-01 4.299564e-01 5.274154e-01 6.183698e-01 7.016979e-01 7.763719e-01 8.414710e-01
```

Does anyone know why these numbers are so different and how I can produce the same results from `Python` in `R`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: fwiw, there are a number of R packages with slightly different ways of making SG filters.  signal, prospectr, and ADPF come to mind.  Many of those build the filter coefficients using convolution and factorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sgolayfilt function in the signal package:

```
library(signal)
packageVersion("signal")
## [1] ‘0.7.7’

apply(X, 2, sgolayfilt, n = 5)
##                [,1]      [,2]
##  [1,] -4.789006e-07 0.9999979
##  [2,]  1.108845e-01 0.9938420
##  [3,]  2.203949e-01 0.9753974
##  [4,]  3.271904e-01 0.9449446
##  [5,]  4.299508e-01 0.9028379
##  [6,]  5.274085e-01 0.8495965
##  [7,]  6.183617e-01 0.7858770
##  [8,]  7.016887e-01 0.7124653
##  [9,]  7.763780e-01 0.6302812
## [10,]  8.414695e-01 0.5403008
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do that but am concerned with the fact that the `signal` package doesn't appear to be updated, which is why I wanted to further understand the `pracma` function.

Comment: It was updated just a few days ago. Be sure you are using the version in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why I am getting an error when trying to upload the newest version?

Comment: Try a different mirror.  Maybe it hasn't reached the one you are using.  Also it is new so even if you are on Windows you may need to compile it from source or wait until CRAN produces a binary.  If all else fails get it directly from its CRAN page: https://cran.r-project.org/package=signal

Comment: Ahh okay, I'm running on Mac, so maybe it's not updated yet.

Answer (score 1):

The SciPy function [`savgol_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) has several options for handling the ends of the input array; see the `mode` parameter in the docstring.

It looks like the behavior of the R function `savgol` corresponds to `mode='constant'` in SciPy's `savgol_filter`. Except for the first value (which is effectively 0 in both cases), this output of `savgol_filter` matches the output of `savgol` in R:

```
In [82]: sfd = savgol_filter(X, window_length=5, polyorder=4, axis=0, mode='constant')

In [83]: sfd[:, 0]
Out[83]: 
array([1.95316193e-17, 1.10882629e-01, 2.20397743e-01, 3.27194697e-01,
       4.29956364e-01, 5.27415386e-01, 6.18369803e-01, 7.01697876e-01,
       7.76371921e-01, 8.41470985e-01])
```

Comment: Ahh okay, do you know how to get the same results with `savgol` without changing the SciPy method? The `R` Documentation provides https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/signal/versions/0.7-6/topics/sgolayfilt this function as a "see also" option which seems to give the correct results but I'm not sure I understand why.

Comment: As noted in the accepted answer, it looks like `sgolayfilt` from the R `signal` package matches the default behavior of `scipy.signal.savgol_filter`.